# Turning a Browser into an Application

Tags: google-chrome, browser, customization, chromium

I´ve been following StackOverflow for a few years, but rarely I needed to post because I could find everything I asked already properly answered.

Now isnt the case, so I suppose it´s a hard topic.

I am building a web application, and need the browser to be customized for the app. Among other things, I need it to be completely full-screen, not have keyboard shortcuts, dont auto-update, dont show default error messages when remote server is down, dont interfere with any already-installed browsers, etc.

I checked Firefox and Chrome, both dont seem to satisfy those needs easily. I was hoping for something much easier, like a real "application-mode" that will turn the browser into something like I described, but theres nothing close to it.

On Chrome I would have to change its source code to make it stop reading some items from the registry (since it would be shared with the real Chrome installation), to make the custom error messages and to disable the keyboard shortcuts; would have to start it using command-line so it loads a different profile; would have to customize that profile so that some plugins are disabled and theres no auto-update, etc, and theres a huge risk I mess it up, or break it on some Windows versions (due to use a different registry or path).

There dont seem to be an easy switch that is pre-tested and guaranteed to work. Chrome´s "App" or "Kiosk" command line switch only seem to put the app into full-screen.

Any light?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you mention working in Windows. Perhaps you could get what you want by building a vanilla version of [Uzbl](http://www.uzbl.org/), which is a minimalist browser built on top of webkit (same as Chrome), although it isn't ported to Windows, it will act in the way you desire. From the readme:

> No built-in means for URL changing, loading/saving of bookmarks, saving history, keybinds, downloads, etc.

However, you'll have to port it to windows from linux yourself. Porting it on top of something like Cygwin/MinGW may be easier.

**[Edit]:** You might have more luck with [Opera's kiosk mode](http://www.opera.com/support/mastering/kiosk/#simple)

Otherwise, if you've already tried the kiosk and application mode for chrome and those were not up to scratch, then the answer is *No, there is no mode that fulfils your needs*. You'll have to dig through the code and change things manually. You may have some luck getting a plugin writer with experience to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will check Uzbl. Anything hints on other browsers?

Comment: Not that I know of. I think if you really want to lock it down as tightly as you say, you'll have to customise the source anyway. Out of interest, why do you need to lock down the browser so tightly?

Comment: We´re releasing an application that is web-based but we dont want the user to know that, to him it will be as if it was a regular desktop application. The reason we didnt make a desktop application is because HTML/CSS/JS is much cheaper/faster to develop than a real desktop application, and the result is usually a better/prettier interface.

Comment: At the risk of being stupid (And I realise _you_ probably don't have a choice in this): why don't you want your users to know the application is web-based?

Comment: It feels a bit more professional, as we can do all the customization (change app name, splash, error screens, etc), and actually we need it to behave like a desktop application: we must make sure it runs on startup, minimize it to tray, installer/uninstaller, dont allow the user to shutdown the app (he can uninstall if he chooses to stop using the app), etc.